# How to use Xamarin Forms Labs ViewModel from XAML?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I tried some MVVM implementation for my Xamarin.Forms project and the XLabs' ViewModel looked the best for me. But I do not really know how to make a, for example, MasterDetail XAML page with it. My TestPage is derived from the ViewBase class. So my first approach was something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<toolkit:BaseView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Mvvm;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
                  x:Class="XLabs.Sample.Pages.Mvvm.MvvmSamplePage"
                  Title="MVVM">
 <toolkit:BaseView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="{Binding NavigateToViewModelButtonText}" Command="{Binding NavigateToViewModel}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </toolkit:BaseView.Content>
</toolkit:BaseView>
```

But inside the BaseView.Content element I can't put another Page. So how to use a MasterDetailPage or a TabbedPage within it?

Comment: I think I mentioned something on your post in the Xamarin Forum. Did you get a response or did my previous post help you?

Comment: Yes, it really helped to understand the structure. Finally I found the source code of BaseView here: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Mvvm/BaseView.cs and I just created another class derived from MasterDetailPage.